# Seaborn horizontal cbar for multiple heatmaps (3x2)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, heatmap

I'm trying to obtain a single cbar for a subplot with 3 rows and 2 columns. I tried multiple ways suggested by different answers here after struggling with it by myself. But still, I'm not able to visualize the cbar in the proper way.

```
#Visualization
palette = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=0, h_pos=120, sep=1, s=100, l=50,
                                  n=12, center="light", as_cmap=True)


#grid_kws = {"height_ratios": (.2, .2), "hspace": .4}
f, axes = plt.subplots(3,2, figsize=(8,12))#, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1,1,1,0.05]})
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes[0], axes[1], axes[2]


sns.heatmap(data=dataset_results["ml1m"][0], annot=True, square=True, vmin=-90., vmax=310., center=0, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.0, cmap=palette, cbar=False, ax=ax0[0],annot_kws={"size": 14}, xticklabels=False)
sns.heatmap(data=dataset_results["ml1m"][1], annot=True, square=True, vmin=-90., vmax=310., center=0, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.0, cmap=palette, ax=ax1[0], cbar=False, annot_kws={"size": 14}, xticklabels=False)
sns.heatmap(data=dataset_results["ml1m"][2], annot=True, square=True, vmin=-90., vmax=310., center=0, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.0, cmap=palette, ax=ax2[0], cbar=False, annot_kws={"size": 14}, cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal", "label": "Percentage increase (%)"})
sns.heatmap(data=dataset_results["lastfm"][0], annot=True, square=True, vmin=-90., vmax=310., center=0, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.0, cmap=palette, ax=ax0[1], cbar=False, annot_kws={"size": 14}, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
sns.heatmap(data=dataset_results["lastfm"][1], annot=True, square=True, vmin=-90., vmax=310., center=0, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.0, cmap=palette, ax=ax1[1], cbar=False, annot_kws={"size": 14}, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
im = sns.heatmap(data=dataset_results["lastfm"][2], annot=True, square=True, vmin=-90., vmax=310., center=0, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.0, yticklabels=False, cmap=palette, ax=ax2[1], cbar=False, annot_kws={"size": 14}, cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal", "label": "Percentage increase (%)"})

#mappable = im.get_children()[0]
#plt.colorbar(mappable, ax = axcb,orientation = 'horizontal')

#print(axes[0][1])
#f.colorbar(g, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())
mappable = im.get_children()[0]
plt.colorbar(mappable, ax = [[ax0[0], ax0[1]], [ax1[0], ax1[1]], [ax2[0], ax2[1]]],orientation = 'horizontal')
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
```

What I get is this plot:

[image]

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` only moves the regularly created subplots here, not the colorbar.  You could try `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)` (or a similar value) after `plt.tight_layout()` to make space for the colorbar.

Comment: It works! I didn't know that about tight_layout in fact I was completely ignoring that it could have been the cause of the error. Thank you!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).